# Не могу понять почему выводит true данный код

Tags: python

Был бы весьма благодарен за разъяснение, почему вывидит true и покакому принципу.

Условие такое:
Рассмотрим задачу о пересечении двух длительных по времени событий. Оба события характеризуются двумя числами - годами начала и конца. Необходимо определить, пересекались ли события во времени, при этом если одно событие началось в тот год, когда закончилось другое - они считаются пересекающимися.

Вот решение

```
start1 = int(input())
finish1 = int(input())
start2 = int(input())
finish2 = int(input())
answer = start1 <= finish2 and start2 <= finish1
print(answer)
```

Почему если ввести значения

```
start1 = 1(x1)
finish1 = 3(y1)
start2 = 2(x2)
finish2 = 4(y2)
```

то выводит true, а если поменять значение start2 на 5, то folse(но это понятно почему, т.к условие не выполняется), но хотя эти два отрезка идентичные, но в одном folse, а в другом true

Ведь отрезок 1,3 и 2,4 вообще не пересекаются если их отобразить на координате x и y

Comment: Не могли бы прояснить, как это работает.

Comment: Здрассти... Как это не пересекаются? Начало второго отрезка (2) лежит посередине первого. А конец первого посередине второго.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Там просто нет никакого `y`, это всё координаты на одной линейной оси `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте просто подставим значения:

```
answer = 1 <= 4 and 2 <= 3
```

Это равно:

```
answer = True and True
answer = True
```

Код у вас верный. Программа работает правильно.